# SQL get row by deadline column

Tags: mysql, datetime

Say I have a table of products that looks like this:

```
| prod_id  | prod_name   | prod_price | prod_deadline      |
|   1      | prod_A 1    | 30.00      | 2015-05-13 04:00:00|
|   2      | prod_A 2    | 40.00      | 2015-06-12 04:00:00|
|   3      | prod_A 3    | 50.00      | 2015-07-21 04:00:00|
```

The idea being that my product A has three different deadlines, the price after May 13 is $30, after June 12 it is $40 and after July 21 it is $50. The column structure, for various business reasons, is set and cannot be changed.

if today is 2015-06-11 16:00:00 what is the MySQL query that will get me the correct price to pay, without looping through in php or whatever language from a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by`, `where` and `limit` for this calculation.  I imagine it would work like this:

```
select p.*
from products p
where prod_name = 'prod A' and prod_deadline <= now()
order by prod_deadline desc
limit 1
```

You may need `like` rather than `=` for the product name.

Comment: Thanks! barking up wrong tree looking for some kind of between comparison, this works great!